# Why am I getting NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, numberformatexception, parseint, stringtokenizer

I did a question in CodeChef platform and the code is getting executed well in my IDE and not in CodeChef Platform.

The same is the case when I use Scanner in place of Buffered Reader, I get NoSuchElementException.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Codechef.main(Main.java:13)
```

Here is the link to the question : https://www.codechef.com/problems/LAYERS

```
/* package codechef; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Codechef
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int T = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        while (T>0)
        {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            int N = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            int C = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            int L[] = new int [N];
            int B[] = new int [N];
            int c[] = new int [N];
            int maxL =0, maxB=0;
            for(int i = 0;i<N;i++)
            {
                st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
                L[i] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                B[i] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                c[i] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                if(maxL<L[i])
                    maxL = L[i];
                if(maxB<B[i])
                    maxB = B[i];
            }
            int Graph[][] = new int[maxL/2][maxB/2];
            for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<L[i]/2;j++)
                {
                    for(int k=0;k<B[i]/2;k++)
                    {
                      Graph[j][k]= c[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            int result[] =new int [C];
            for(int i=0;i<maxL/2;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<maxB/2;j++)
                {
                    if(Graph[i][j]>0)
                    {
                        result[Graph[i][j]-1]++;
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int i=0; i<C;i++)
            {
                System.out.print(result[i]*4+" ");
            }
            T--;
        }
    }
}
```

Help me why I am getting the Error.

Comment: What input you are giving from console?

Comment: The CodeChef evaluates using a set of test inputs from the Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I can count to line 13 (which is always shaky in code posted here), your exception is coming from this line:

```
int T = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

`br.readLine()` returns `null` when there is no more input. Since this is your first call to `readLine()`, it means that your input is empty. The `null` in your exception message means that a `null` was passed to `parseInt` (or the string `"null"`, but that’s unlikely).

This explanation for your error also agrees with your reported `NoSuchElementException` from `Scanner`.

Tip: I know that your variables come from a problem statement that used `T`, `N`, `C`, `L` and `B` in uppercase. Still in Java, let the Java naming conventions win: use lowercase for variables. So `t` or `capitalT`. The variable name `T` is particularly confusing since `T` is very often used as a type parameter in generics.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I will use naming convention win the next time.

Comment: So, I guess there is a problem with the test inputs being provided or else there shouldn't be this error.